# Node reference in view

Tags: drupal-6, view, hyperlink

I have a node reference I am trying to use in a view. I have added the node reference and the title to my fields and cannot get the node reference or the title to rewite properly. I am trying to use tokens but I cannot get the raw link or uri value of the node. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<a href='[field_featured_work_nid]'>[title]<a/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use aliases..use pathmodule for it..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the referenced node as a relationship in the view. At that point you can add a field to the view for the node path, and require the relationship for the referenced node. That should get you what you need.